# Strange error in Ansible regarding regex

Tags: regex, ansible, yaml

```
replace:
    path: "{{ drupal.install_dir }}/{{ drupal.project_name }}/sites/default/settings.php"
    regexp: '(\s+)(\'database\' => \'{{ drupal.database_name }}\',)$'
    replace: '\1\2\n\1\'charset\' => \'utf8mb4\',\n\1\'collation\' => \'utf8mb4_unicode_ci\','
```

But gives error:

```
path: "{{ drupal.install_dir }}/{{ drupal.project_name }}/sites/default/settings.php"
regexp: '(\s+)(\'database\' => \'{{ drupal.database_name }}\',)$'
                 ^ here
```

But it works in https://regex101.com/

Comment: Where are the error contents? And why not simply enclose the whole expression in double quotes? Instead of escaping single ones.

Comment: @techraf I don't think double quotes works (at least not for me, I already tried, and all the examples are single quoted). The error content is the one I show you, just with some trash. Basically says that there is an syntax error. If I flip the regex and replace, the error appears in the replace, right next to a escaped single quote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double-quotes (you need to repeat backslashes then):

```
replace:
    path: "{{ drupal.install_dir }}/{{ drupal.project_name }}/sites/default/settings.php"
    regexp: "(\\s+)('database' => '{{ drupal.database_name }}',)$"
    replace: "\\1\\2\\n\\1'charset' => 'utf8mb4',\\n\\1'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',"
```

Comment: Thanks, this is clearer. Do you know how to make this "only apply once"?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: If I run this multiple times, I get the "replace" added multiple times... well it is not even a replace, its more like an append (if you look at the regex, I capture the line and put two more lines)

Comment: That's how you wrote regex, isn't it? if you copy the result to source in regex101 and try again, you don't end up with duplicated content?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround:

```
replace:
        path: "{{ drupal.install_dir }}/{{ drupal.project_name }}/sites/default/settings.php"
        regexp: '^(\s+)(\x27database\x27 => \x27{{ drupal.database_name }}\x27,)$'
        replace: '\1\2\n\1"charset" => "utf8mb4",\n\1"collation" => "utf8mb4_general_ci",'
```

Luckily I can swap double quotes and single quotes (PHP array). The \x27 workaround does not work in the replace, but it does in the regex. (\x27 = ')

Answer (score 0):

Within a [single quote style scalar](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2788097), you have to "escape" any single quotes that are part of that scalar with an extra single quote:

```
   regexp: '(\s+)(\''database\'' => \''{{ drupal.database_name }}\'',)$'
   replace: '\1\2\n\1\''charset\'' => \''utf8mb4\'',\n\1\''collation\'' => \''utf8mb4_unicode_ci\'','
```

no other characters need to be (or can be) escaped, within those single quote style scalars.